# Python 2.7 Unpickling Error - "cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'x'."

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, pickle

I am trying to unpickle a .pkl file however I am getting the error, "cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'x'."

I have tried using the python libraries pickle, cPickle and joblib from sklearn.metrics.

Trying to load the 103 MB .pkl file from sklearn.metrics gives me the memory error, "self.memo[repr(i)] = self.stack[-1]
MemoryError"

Both pickle and cPickle give me the "cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'x'." error

Here is the following code:

```
import cPickle as pickle

pickle_file = open("haystack-vect_all-source_2017-05-24.pkl","rb")

data = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

Here is a link to the haystack-vect_all-source_2017-05-24.pkl file I am trying to unpickle: https://github.com/MPEDS/mpeds/tree/master/mpeds/mpeds/classifiers

Please let me know of any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a pickle file; it contains ZLIB-compressed data.  Perhaps the decompressed data is a valid pickle (I didn't check that far).